# TLS with out-of-band Pre-shared keys (PSKs) in Golang

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.3

I'm looking for a way to establish TLS sessions using *out-of-bound* PSK in Go. I control both the server and client.

Reading [Golang TLS implementation](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/handshake_server_tls13.go), it seems like the library only supports PSK in session resumption where PSKs are obtained from previous sessions. In my scenario, though, PSK are established between the server and the client out-of-band, which AFAIK is "permitted" according to [RFC 8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-2.3) ("TLS PSKs can be established out of band.") Does anyone know if Go supports that already or if there are other TLS libraries that do?

Answer (score 1):

`TLS-PSK` (or the RSA/DHE variants) is not currently (Go 1.15) supported in the standard library.

There is [an issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6379) that has been open since 2013 but no movement on it. Multiple comments in that issue advertise forks of `crypto/tls` with purported support for external pre-shared keys; use at your own risk.